# Can my architecture of authentication be used in a real world application?

Tags: authentication, architecture, authorization, microservices, backend

I'm trying to create an authentication flow for user using Auth0 3rd party auth provider.
I've never done proper auth before, so I wanted to ask experts opinion if my approach is valid, are there any potential vulnerabilities, issues or any other type of problems with my approach. Here's a diagram I've created representing the registration flow.
[image: Auth0 registration flow]
I'm hoping to use AWS SQS for message queuing.

So loging in is pretty clear. Auth0 authenticates the user, issues the token, and then when from FE user tries to access backend, just validate the token against Auth0 credentials and that's it. However, the registration flow is something that I want advice with.

Any advice on improving the flow is highly appreciated.

I'm wondering if notifying FE about the fact that user information was stored successfully in BE is good. My current approach would be to push a message/notification through SSE (server sent event) and then client would listen for some that message. When client receives the confirmation, then user is authenticated to the application.